# Repetitive javascript cycle

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

good night, I have this view (the image) which is part of an invoice, this is precisely the detail of the invoice, and I have in this detail a javascript function so that while I write the name of the product I look for the product in the database and when I select it I fill the input of the unit price corresponding to that product, until there all wonders, but the problem is that by pressing the + button to enter a new line and load a new product the function javascript no longer works, it occurred to me that I can use a foreach or something similar to make that function work every time a new line is inserted but I can not make it work, I leave the code:

```
//search in the database
$("#inputPrecioProducto").devbridgeAutocomplete({
        showNoSuggestionNotice: true,
        serviceUrl: '/maderas/facturar/leer_productos',
        noSuggestionNotice: 'No se encontraron datos',
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            $('#inputIdProducto').val(suggestion.data)
            $('#inputPrecioUnidad').val(suggestion.precio_unidad);
        }
    });}






// Product Field Repeater



$('.repeater').repeater({
                hide: function (deleteElement) {
                var elemento=$(this);
                swal({   
                    title: "Estas Seguro?",   
                    text: "Se borrará toda la fila!",   
                    type: "warning",   
                    showCancelButton: true,   
                    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",   
                    confirmButtonText: "Si, bórralo!",
                    cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',   
                    closeOnConfirm: false
                }, function(){   

                    swal("Producto Borrado!", "Se ha eliminado el Producto.", "success"); 

                    elemento.remove();
                    sumarTotales();
                    crearIgv();
                });

        },
        isFirstItemUndeletable: true

    });
// ./ Product Field Repeater
```

Comment: after you add a new line with the + button, can you use jquery to select the new line and set repeater on it? `$('.repeater:last').repeater(...`

Comment: yes, but it has not worked for me that way